# In NodeJS, is it possible to run a Node server on a subdirectory?

Tags: node.js, tomcat, server-side

Instead of having `Node.js` cover an entire port or subdomain, can I run a Node Server on just a sub directory like this:

[* means anything]

#### Example:

```
http://example.com/ - Tomcat Server
http://example.com/my-node-server/ - NodeJS Server
http://example.com/* - Tomcat Server
http://example.com/my-node-server/* - NodeJS Server
```

Answer (score 3):

There are probably a variety of ways to do this, but I believe this is the easiest:

Try running your node server on a different port, then redirect requests to /my-node-server/ in Tomcat to the node port.

Exactly how you do this is very implementation specific and I only have experience with Node.js (not Tomcat).  However, you should be able to take the request in Tomcat, alter it such that the Node port is in the url (mysite.com/my-node-server/ becomes localhost:port/my-node-server/).  Then in Node, if you use a framework like 'express', you can designate the port that you listen for, such as with `app.listen(port)`

Comment: Good idea, but how can I do this?